# How to Connect to CRM 2011 from windows Azure worker role

Tags: .net, windows, dynamics-crm-2011, azure-worker-roles

I have developed one web application using .Net 4.0. Now i want to host that application on windows  azure. when i have write the code for establishing the connection with CRM 2011 online in worker role then it works fine and i am able to establish the connection successfully. But when i try to connect to the CRM 2011 on-premise server from my worker role it throws an error while establishing the connection . For this,I am using service reference of CRM 2011 on-premise into my application. Please help.

Comment: Please input your thoughts. Will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The error that I am getting is "metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved".

Answer (score 0):

Is your on-premise deployment Internet-Facing?

> metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved

You encounter this error if the server endpoint cannot be reached - whether it is physically incorrect (e.g. typo) or network restrictions prevent access (firewall, routing, server config) etc.

Comment: I am not sure whrether the deployment is Internet Facing? How do I confirm it?? I am sorry, as I dont have much knowledge in this domain. I just started to learn it.. Please help..

Comment: Your CRM administrator should know this. If you are the CRM administrator then it is highly likely your deployment is not Internet Facing. If your code is executing in the cloud, it will need access to your CRM deployment - i.e. your CRM deployment will need to be configured for Internet Facing Deployment. This is no small task in CRM 2011.